# Button text automatically change to capital letter in android

Tags: android, button, text, uppercase

I have a button in my xml layout

```
         <Button
             android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
             android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
             android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:text="Default ringtone"
             android:id="@+id/select_ringtone"
                     />
```

and when I set any text on it automatically change to capital letter .even when I set in xml or in fragment.and I dont know what is the problem !!!!  I am developing  an app for a while but suddenly I faced this problem and it made me confused

Comment: You may also want to consider checking the style that you are using as it might be using a font that is naturally in all caps.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I assume, You using **23 API Level** .Its default there.
Don't worry.

Just add

```
android:textAllCaps="false"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot you saved my time.but I dont know why it happend becuase I   am developping an app and suddenly I faced this problem

Answer (score 0):

use TextView Like this

```
            <TextView
             android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
             android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
             android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="Default ringtone"
             android:id="@+id/select_ringtone"
                     />
```

in this case your text show in small letters

Answer (score -1):

Programmatically change the transformation method of the button.   `btn.setTransformationMethod(null);`

OR

```
<style name="MyButton" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
    </style>
```